# The use the word "earthly"

Tags: poetic

Does using the word "earthly" describing a person make sense? As in "he is earthly", "are you earthly" etc.? Does it make/doesn't make sense 100% or is it somewhere in between? (Try to think about the phrase in a poetic context and not in an academic/daily situation. That is my intention)

Comment: Don't confuse _earthly_ (with an L) with _earthy_ (without an L). They have very different meanings, and only one of them is used to describe people.

Comment: Have you looked up a dictionary? "He is earthly" makes sense if you mean "He isn't from Mars", "he's not a ghost" or "his focus is on materialistic rather than spiritual matters". But in poetry you can use a word in non-standard ways, so it's impossible to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Earthly** refers to *things of the Earth*, as opposed to things that are [divine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divinity), supernatural, imaginary or otherwise *not of the Earth*.

You could say, for example, that a person was too *earthly* to put much stock in the promises of the Church.

It’s not a common adjective for people, though. You’ll find it more frequently in comparisons of the natural and the “supernatural”, e.g. *there was no earthly way he could have scored that goal*, suggesting to the listener that the athlete in question must have had abilities beyond those of the ordinary man or woman. It isn’t meant literallly.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: 
"earthly" means "pertaining to the earth" 
If you want to describe someone as earthly, you must specify somehow in what respect they are earthly. Here are some questions that might arise from that description: is his skin-tone earthly? is he not ethereal? is his mind strong as the earth? is it his eyes that are of earthen tones? is he belonging to the earth? is he attached to the earth?

You must specify what about him is earthly, if you do not mean to say exactly this: that he is the opposite of ethereal (of the sky).